# Getting mass addresses current balance

Tags: address, api

How can i get the current balance of massive addresses?
I'm getting address balances now on blockchain.info but I need to check about 1000 of addresses in one minute.

The issue is that they blocking my requests every once in a while.

I do tried to look for open XML RPC API but I didn't find one.

How can i make this happen and check many addresses as possible?

P.S
I know that I can have my node but for only checking addresses its seems to me way to overkill + holding 200gb server only for node will costs.

thanks.